# Java hierarchy and access level

Tags: java

In my java application I want to solve the following scenario

```
class C {

}

Class A extends C {
    public A() {
        B objB=new B(this);
        objB.methodA();
    }

    public void methodX() {

    }
}

Class B {
    private A objA;
    public B(A a) {
        objA=a; 
    }
    public void methodA() {
        objA.methodX()
    }
}
```

Is it possible to call methodX() of A from Class B. When I compile the code the objA(in class B) gives access only to Class C methods? Is alternate way exists for solving the above scenario?? Plz help

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. `methodX()` of A should be callable anywhere since it's declared public

Comment: I am passing 'this' as constructor parameter to class B from class A, when it reaches in Class B is it point towards class C (the superclass)  ???????

Comment: The caution with passing `this` in a constructor is that an object may not be fully initialized if you try to call methods on it

Comment: @gobernador I would not caution whole cyclic chain is stinky but may be a dumbed down version of a bigger possibly more stinkier code :) . Instead of cautioning him on passing `this` question should be why on earth would he do that any way because even for an immutable object this will be so tightly coupled with the sequence in which the code is in.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the fact that it makes no sense what you are trying to do and code is weired there is nothing wrong with it Semantically . I just tried it like below.

```
package com.test;

public class So {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
        B b = new B(a);
        b.methodA();

    }

}

class A extends C {

    public A() {

        B objB = new B(this);
        objB.methodA();
    }

    public void methodX() {

    }

}

class B {

    private A objA;

    public B(A a) {

        objA = a;

    }

    public void methodA() {

        objA.methodX();

    }
}

class C {

}
```

---

here is an other variant for `main(String[] args)` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
        C ca = new A();
        B b2 = new B((A)ca); // This is typcasting
        b2.methodA();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks. Actually I call it from inside a listner.There lies the problem. outside  it works OK as mentioned by you.

Comment: Yes not sure how you are calling it in reality but type casting is what you might be after . e.g. done on this line ` B b2 = new B((A)ca); ` . Note the variable `ca` is of type `C` and casted to subtype `A` here.